# How to do "Flatten" action on Confluent KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a json structured data like

> {"name": "foo", "hobbies": ["music", "food", "travel"]}

My question is how to transform it into 3 records in KSQL:

> {"name":"foo", "hobby":"music"} {"name":"foo", "hobby":"food"}
>   {"name":"foo", "hobby":"travel"}

Answer (score 2):

Currently KSQL doesn't support flattening/exploding a nested list, but there [is an open issue tracking the feature request](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/527).